# Three divs with auto width get as wide as the widest div, make each div as wide as its content

Tags: html, css

I have three divs `.yellow-element` that has a `width: auto` style and are located inside a table column which width is also `auto`. It results in both the table getting as wide as the widest div **and** each div getting that wide, even if it's not necesasry content-wise:

```css
#info-table td {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;

}

.info-table-1  {

    width: 100px;
}

.info-table-2  {
    width: auto;
}

.yellow-element  {
    font-size: 100%;    
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--body-font-color);
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 20px;

    width: auto;
    height: 30px;

    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table id="info-table">
  <tr>
    <td class='info-table-1'>Total Something:</td>
    <td class='info-table-2'>
       100500/100500
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr><td class='info-table-1'>Yellow Elements:</td>
    <td class='info-table-2'>
      <div class='yellow-element' title='title1'>long long long long long long long long long long long long long text</div>

      <div class='yellow-element' title='title2'>average average average text </div>

      <div class='yellow-element' title='title3'>small text</div>

    </td></tr>
</table>
```

The answers I've seen suggest putting `display: inline-block` for class `.yellow-element`, but while it does work, fixing the width of each div individually, it puts all of them on the same line, which is not something I'd prefer.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeaXbL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `.info-table-2` into a flex container. Then you can control the layout of the `yellow-element` cells more easily.

```css
#info-table td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.info-table-1 {
  width: 100px;
}

.info-table-2 {
  /* width: auto; */         /* <-- removed */
  display: flex;             /* <-- added */
  flex-direction: column;    /* <-- added */
  align-items: flex-start;   /* <-- added */
}

.yellow-element {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--body-font-color);
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table id="info-table">
  <tr>
    <td class='info-table-1'>Total Something:</td>
    <td class='info-table-2'>
      100500/100500
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class='info-table-1'>Yellow Elements:</td>
    <td class='info-table-2'>
      <div class='yellow-element' title='title1'>long long long long long long long long long long long long long text</div>

      <div class='yellow-element' title='title2'>average average average text </div>

      <div class='yellow-element' title='title3'>small text</div>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r3bwqn4u/1/

Answer (score 1):

use the below:

```
.yellow-element {
   clear:both;
   float:left;
}
```